# backbonejs: the collection initialize in view module have only one model

Tags: javascript, collections, backbone.js

I have a `model`:

```
window.LayerModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

        defaults:{
            'id':'unknow',
            'type':'unkonw',
            'preId':'unknow',

            'data': {}
        }
}
```

then I defined a collection:

```
window.LayerManageCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model: LayerModel
    })
```

then I init it in view:

```
        window.LayerMasterManageView = Backbone.View.extend({

              initialize: function () {
                  //here I have a gobal javascript variable named "localdata"
                  //which have 17 items in an array,each of them is object type

                  this.collection = new LayerManageCollection(localdata);
                  console.log('this collection', this.collection);
              }
}
```

but the collection's length is 1!,and only have one model!,

the strange thing is ,if a change the `"defaults"` to `"default"`,the collection result is as I desired ,which length is 17

Why this happen? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you read this before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611977/backbone-js-not-rendering

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the default `idAttribute` for a model is `id`. Because you're defining the `id` in your `defaults` you're going to always create the same model, since Backbone errors quietly when a duplicate model is created, that's why you only see 1 model.

Comment: An this also explains why it works properly when he changes `defaults` to `default`

Answer (score 0):

i think your problem is with the objects present in your `localdata`.
how many objects in your `localdata` have different `id` field
either you should provide different id to every object in your `localdata` array or just remove the `id` field from `defaults` in the model `LayerModel`

whenever you change the name from `defaults` to `default` then because there is no default id backbone takes it as a new model and hence adds it to the collection.
**so you can change `defaults` to any other name like `abc` and it will have the same behaviour**